How can I derive the bivariate breakdown of a multiple linear regression?

I recently start to learn causal inference from this website. It claims that "efficient of a multivariate regression is the bivariate coefficient of the same regressor after accounting for the effect of other variables in the model". How can I understand it? Can someone help derive the math proof?

Have a look at the answer here.

These questions differ. @dd ss asks about the OLS estimate after residualizing the independent variable $T$. The question you linked asks about the OLS estimate after residualizing the dependent variable $y$.

This can be shown by applying the formula for block matrix inversion.
Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
\beta &= \left( \begin{bmatrix} T & X \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} T & X \end{bmatrix} \right)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} T & X \end{bmatrix}^T y
&= \begin{bmatrix} T^T T& T^T X \\ X^T T& X^T X \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} T^T y \\ X^T y \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
Using the block matrix inversion formula (2) from the above link, we calculate the first entry to be
$$
\begin{align*}
\beta_1 &=  
\begin{bmatrix}
(T^T T - X^T T (T^T T)^{-1} T^T X)^{-1} & (T^T T - X^T T (T^T T)^{-1} T^T X)^{-1} \ X^T T (T^T T)^{-1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T^T y \\ X^T y \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
(T^T M_X T)^{-1}  & (T^T M_X T)^{-1} \ X^T T (T^T T)^{-1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} T^T y \\ X^T y \end{bmatrix} \\
&= (T^T M_X T)^{-1} T^T M_X y = ( (M_X T)^T (M_X T) )^{-1} (M_X T)^T y,
\end{align*}
$$
where $M_X = (\mathrm{Id} - X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T)$ is the projection onto the orthogonal complement of the linear subspace spanned by $X$.
Linearly regressing $T \sim X$ yields an estimate $(X^T X)^{-1} X^T T$ and thus residuals $T - X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T T = M_X T$. Thus, $\beta_1$ is the result of linearly regressing $y$ on $M_X T$, the residuals after linearly regressing $T$ on $X$.
